# Way to Accessing Resources and Resource Ids of other Apps

Tags: android, android-resources

After some research and practice, I have observed that we can access Resources of other Apps using [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) like

```
Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(appPackageName);
```

but merely accessing `Resources` is not sufficient. We need Ids for every Resource component like Drawables, layouts,Strings etc etc... to access them from Resources.

I have searched in SO and struggled a lot myself about how to get Resource Ids of other Apps but didn't get proper solution. I have seen in SO, some people suggested to use methods like

```
resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage);
resources.getValue(String name, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs);
resources.getValue(int id, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs);
```

but don't have Idea how to use them.

I need to access Resources(Drawables, Strings, Layouts...) of other Apps.

Help me in this concern. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

thank you all
and sorry for my english...

Comment: If that happens, it would be serious security breach.

Comment: @AbhishekV as we are able to get the Resources, I hope we can get resources components like Drawables,layouts etc etc... isn't it?

Comment: @GopalRao Ya we can get the resources. But to get drawables out of the Resources object, we need to know the name/id of that drawable. We would know its know only if we are the developers of both the applications.

Comment: Do you want to access the resources of any unknown application or the application which you have developed?

Comment: @GrIsHu Resources of any other application. they may be developed by me or others...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question,
I can able to access via following code. It is working fine..

```
String lAppPkg = "com.example.sharedlogos";
resources = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getResourcesForApplication(lAppPkg);
int lID = resources.getIdentifier( mID, "drawable",
                            lAppPkg);
mImage.setBackground(resources.getDrawable(lID));
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not have time to go through perfectly but this should do:

https://github.com/alt236/Android-Drawables---Android

This project tries to get all the drawables at least from other app. This also is available on Google Play: [Android Resource Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.androidDrawables)

Comment: but they clearly mentioned that `This application will list all public and private Android resources (i.e. resources located under 'android.R.*' and under 'com.android.internal.R.*') for the current device.`... but not Resources of other Apps...